# nodejs mongoose remove hits Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to read and update and remove some documents. 

The find and update and remove are working fine. Except the last `data.remove();` which is not being removed and hits an error.
I am getting this error in my code below:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
    Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and the line that it is pointing to is:

```
res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
```

at the end of the code.

```
router.post('/some/route', function (req, res) {
    if (req.isLoggedIn()) {
        return res.status(403).json({});
    }
    MyModel.findById(req.user._id,function (err, data) {
        if(err || data.rights !== 'super'){
            return res.status(403).json({});
        }
        if(req.body.writer){
            Books.update(
                { writer : req.body.id},
                { $set : { writer : req.body.writer} },
                function (err) {
                    if(err){
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        res.status(200).send('updated successfully.');
                    }
                }
            );
        }else{
            Books.remove({writer: req.body.id}, function(err){
                if (err){ return console.log(err)}
            });
        }

        MetaInfo.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.body.id}, function (err, data) {
            console.log(err);            
        });
        Archive.findOne({_id: req.body.id},function (err, data) {

            smtpTransporter.sendMail({...}, function (error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log("Mail sent");
                }
                smtpTransporter.close();
            });

            data.remove();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'server error',
                    err: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that one of the res.status/send has been executed before that statement. Try and console.log before every res.status statement so that you can track all the conditional blocks the statement the code has branched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you do res.send or res.json it sets headers for response. When javascript finds another res.send to execute after one, it throws error that the headers are already set.

Make sure you are returning the res.send or json every time or you are using proper if else statement for it.

To elaborate :

Example 1 :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 if(true){ 
  res.send('first');
 } 
 res.send('second');
});
```

This will throw error in console.

Example 2 :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 if(true){ 
  return res.send('first');
 } 
 res.send('second');
});
```

No error thrown.

Example 3 :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 if(true){ 
  res.send('first')
 } 
 else{ 
  res.send('second');
 }
});
```

No error thrown.

Comment: suppose i have multiple res.send in one route and how can I append them all into one, so that I can get the success response from all into one?

Comment: If you want to accumulate all errors and respond at once at the end, you can initialize a variable 'errors' as null at the start of route function. Whenever you get error, push it into that variable. At the end check if errors is null respond with success or if its present, send the error json. I hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: could you give your example using my above code in the question?

Comment: i created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831153/nodejs-express-response-append-into-a-list
i would be thankful if you could respond to it.